# "C:\mywork" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: java

Learning some basic Java and one task is trying to open a .java using the Command Line. I've got a .Java located in a new folder at "C:\mywork" Trying to first navigate to the folder but im getting that error.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should learn some basic `cmd.exe` first...

Comment: Have you tried `cd C:\mywork`?

Comment: First of all, you sholud paste the code and the error.

Second, It seems that you have not your classpath correctly configured. Get us more info please.

Comment: learn some basic dos cmd.. google dos commands

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the cd (Change Directory) command:

```
cd c:\mywork
```

Then you can use the dir command to list the contents of the directory.  Refer to this tutorial on the windows command line: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr05/cos126/cmd-prompt.html

Answer (score 0):

use `cd C:\mywork` if c: is the default drive, otherwise first enter `C:` in cmd and then enter `cd C:\mywork` . Then you can continue with `javac Sample.java` and `java Sample` etc